# Create View by Code First from EF Core 3.1

Tags: view, code-first, ef-core-3.1

I want to create sql view like a table at EF Core by Code First. How can I do this? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help you

Entity:

```
public class Personel  
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public DbSet<Personel> Personels { get; set; }
```

On Model Creating:

```
builder.Entity<Personel>(eb => {
    eb.HasNoKey();
    eb.ToView("View_Personel");
    eb.Property(v => v.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
});
```

Add-Migration

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("
    CREATE VIEW View_Personel AS
        SELECT MatchValue AS Name
        FROM Personel");
```

In addition, you can create with SQL Method Procedure, Materialized View, etc. by Code First (not DBFirst).